# Compare data from different timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

What I have is a table with restaurants, a restaurant is either active (1) or inactive (0). This can change weekly. I want to determine how many restaurants have been deactivated since last week. E.g. if a restaurant was `active = 1` in Week 50, but `active = 0` in Week 51 then it should be counted. Hence, I want to compare `active` on a weekly basis.

My table looks like this:

```
restaurant | week_nm | active | date
-----------------------------------------
rest1      | 50      | 1      | xxx-xx-xx
rest1      | 51      | 0      | xxx-xx-xx
rest2      | 50      | 1      | xxx-xx-xx
rest2      | 51      | 1      | xxx-xx-xx
rest3      | 50      | 1      | xxx-xx-xx
rest3      | 51      | 0      | xxx-xx-xx
```

What I want to have is this:

```
week_nm | restaurants_deactivated
---------------------------------
51      | 2
```

A count of restaurants that went from `active = 1` to `active = 0`.

Comment: Do you have year column? Change between 51/1 week

Comment: Yes, I do have a year column, I made the table very basic to illustrate what I want. I'll update my question.

Comment: Please add it to your question. It is important for correct answer.

Comment: Tricky when it comes to New year. Last week one year compared to the first week the following year.

Comment: Does the `date` column correctly reflect the week number?

Answer (score 2):

As jarlh commented correctly, taking the year change into account will be a bit complicated. So if the `date` column (btw: a horrible name for a column) correctly reflects the week in which the the restaurant was active or not, then you can use the ISO year/week combination (derived from that date) to properly deal with the year change:

```
select to_char(r1.date, 'iyyy-iw'), count(*)
from rest r1
where to_char(r1.date, 'iyyy-iw') = '2015-51'
  and not active
  and exists (select 1 
              from rest r2
              where to_char(to_date(to_char(r1.date, 'iyyy-iw'), 'iyyy-iw') - 7, 'iyyy-iw') = to_char(r2.date, 'iyyy-iw')
                and r2.restaurant = r1.restaurant
                and r2.active)
group by to_char(date, 'iyyy-iw')
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/8da24/2

`to_char(r1.date, 'iyyy-iw')` calculates the year **and** week number based on the [ISO definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Week#Week_numbering) of the week in the year. This returns e.g. 2015-51 for 2015-12-21.

The part:

```
where to_char(r1.date, 'iyyy-iw') = '2015-51'
  and not active
```

retrieves all rows from week 51 where the restaurant was not active (this assumes that `active` is a boolean column).

The tricky part is to calculate the "previous" week. This is done using the expression:

```
to_char(to_date(to_char(r1.date, 'iyyy-iw'), 'iyyy-iw') - 7, 'iyyy-iw')
```

The "date" `2015-51` is converted back to a date, which result in the first day of that week. Then 7 days are subtracted and the result of that date, is then converted back into the year/week display. This is then used in the co-related subquery. The effect of that is, that it returns all rows that have been active in the "previous" week (`where exists (...)`)

This should work from December to January as well (just keep in mind that e.g. the ISO week #1 in 2016 starts on January 4th).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select top 1 (a.[week_nm]) as [week_nm], (select count(b.active) from [as] b where b.[week_nm] = a.[week_nm] and b.active=0) as restaurants_deactivated from [as] a order by a.[week_nm] desc
```

Comment: `a.[week_nm]` is invalid SQL

Comment: But it's invalid (standard) SQL and it will not work in Postgres (which this question is about, not Microsoft T-SQL). And `top 1` is also invalid in Postgres (and standard SQL)

Comment: ok i got it Mr a_horse_with_no_name thanks for your concern. I hope my MS SQL Query may help logically to write query in postgresql, I don't know the syntax of postgresql. thanks